# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Hello there can someone please help me with this one? I don't understand this error. Thank you!

LogCat:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.musicapp.android.musicapp/com.musicapp.android.musicapp.PlayingScreen}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 0
    **at com.musicapp.android.musicapp.PlayingScreen.getIntentMethod(PlayingScreen.java:100)**
```

code:

```
    private void getIntentMethod() {
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
        song_list = newSong_list;
        if (song_list != null) {
99            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
100            uri = Uri.parse(song_list.get(position).getPath());
        } else {
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
```

Comment: post make `newSong_list` part please.

Answer (score 0):

index out of bound exception appears when you try to access item at invalid index, i.e when list don't have item at that index

for fix you can do as below :

```
 private void getIntentMethod() {
    position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
    song_list = newSong_list;
    if (song_list != null && !song_list.isEmpty()) {
       pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
       uri = Uri.parse(song_list.get(position).getPath());
    } else {
        pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }
```